# DeadLock in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, locking, deadlock

I'm programing a GUI with `tkinter` that uses `cv2` to extract the video stream from the computer camera. To do that, a `Thread` reloads the image using a while loop.

I have been using `Locks` so both `Threads` (the main one and the auxiliar) end their process as expected. However, i'm not able to do that because of a DeadLock that I can't identify.

The code is the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import time
import sys
import threading
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Application:
    gui_root = None
    gui_panel = None

    frame = None
    video_capture = None
    stop_event = None
    thread = None
    thread_lock = None

    def __init__(self):

        self.gui_root = tk.Tk()
        self.gui_root.geometry("640x480")
        self.gui_root.resizable(False, False)

        self.video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.thread_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.load_frame, args=())
        self.thread.start()

        self.gui_root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

    def start(self):

        self.gui_root.mainloop()

    def load_frame(self):

        print('Starting load_frame')

        while self.thread_lock.acquire() and not self.stop_event.is_set():

                _, self.frame = self.video_capture.read()
                self.frame = cv2.resize(self.frame, (640, 480))

                c_image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                c_image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(c_image))

                if self.gui_panel is None:
                    self.gui_panel = tk.Label(image=c_image_tk)
                    self.gui_panel.place(width=640, height=480, x=0, y=0)
                else:
                    self.gui_panel.configure(image=c_image_tk)

                self.thread_lock.release()

        print("End of while")
        self.thread_lock.release()
        print('End of Process 2')

    def on_close(self):

        self.stop_event.set()
        print("Event set")
        with self.thread_lock:
            self.video_capture.release()
            self.gui_root.destroy()


app = Application()
app.start()
```

Comment: In general, you can only do Tk stuff on the main thread. If you do something like creating a new Label on a worker thread, depending on your platform, exact details of your code, whether it’s Tuesday, etc., it may work, do nothing, crash, hang, or hang until the main thread gets a chance to run the event loop. The last one would cause a literal deadlock, and some of the others might look like a deadlock if you’re not being very precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem here is that you're attempting to do Tkinter stuff, like creating a new `tk.Label`, from a background thread, and that's not allowed.

My first guess is that what's happening is that the Tk code on the background thread is just hanging—which isn't really a deadlock, but since you've got a thread hanging forever while holding a lock, nobody else will ever acquire that lock, so it's much the same effect.

The only way to solve this is to have your background thread(s) post messages to a queue requesting GUI stuff to get done for them, and have the main thread poll that queue each time through the event loop (e.g., via an `after` function).

The old `mttkinter` project wrapped this up transparently, but unfortunately it was never updated for modern Python. A few years ago, I slapped together a quick port (at https://github.com/abarnert/mttkinter), but I never tested it rigorously, and I don't know if anyone's ever used it for anything serious.

But you could try this at least for a quick test. If it makes no difference, then you've probably ruled out Tk threading issues; if it makes a difference, great (although that difference could be "now it doesn't freeze up, but it crashes 50% of the time—in which case you're not done, and can't trust `mttkinter` as-is, but at least you know that Tk threading is the thing you have to solve).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With a lot of lost hours trying to make `tkinter` work and your answer I've finally decided to use OpenCV directly.